# Как сделать слайд анимацию на vue.js + flexbox?

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox

Нужно сделать слайд анимацию на vue.js, при этом использовать `position:absolute` я не хочу, так как это требует фиксированной высота для родительского блока.

Я попробовал добавить `display:flex` в `.slider` и это работает, но блок slide во время анимации сплющивает по ширине, плюс между блоками образуется отступ.

Как сделать это корректно?

https://jsfiddle.net/mezhevikin/eywraw8t/358967/ .

**html:**

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="slider">
        <transition name="slide">
            <div class="text" :key="index">
                {{ items[index].text }}
            </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
    <a @click="next" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
 body {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

#app {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.slider {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
}

.slide {
    width:100%;
}

.slide-leave-active,
.slide-enter-active {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.slide-enter {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}

.slide-leave-to {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

Comment: `<transition name="slide" mode="out-in">` – без position absolute работает отлично в вашем примере, но нельзя добиться эффекта наложения во время анимации. Хотя я в одном проекте сделал, только по коду не найду и не вспомню как именно. Но могу боевой пример показать

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Привет. Да, знаю о out-in. Но нужно чтобы одновременно , один блока уезжает, второй выезжает

Comment: да, откопал у себя, всетаки absolute у меня в решении. Но ловите решение для вашей проблемы – `.slide-enter, .slide-leave-to { position: absolute; }` – высота родителя сохраняется, если ставить только на время анимации

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev спасибо. Работает, пока подводных камней не нашел. Сделайте ответ, я отмечу его как решение.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Все таки нашел подводные камни. в ios 8,9,10. выглядит косячно. Хотя в ie11 работает

Comment: так это же не android, эти версии мертвые как ie6

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev 8 - да. 9-10 нет. У меня 5% пользователей проекта на них)